# How to remove content of iFrame WITHOUT cross domain security on?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have been successfully integrating an iFrame from another domain with the class "iFrame1". I expect that the cross domain security is not enabled (or disabled for us since we are whitelisted at the provider).

After  I execute the following jquery:

`$('.iFrame1').contents().find('.footer').remove();`

I see still the div is pending. I don't see another error in console. So wondering what cause the error of this?

Made an example of this at: https://jsfiddle.net/w2Lfap7m/25/

Comment: This is your own website https://aanbod.move.nl?

Comment: No, otherwise i simply could changed the source....as mentioned they are a supplier we are allowed to use conent from. We just want to hide unneeded data.